# close the window popup using JS

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

Writng script for closing window which i get as a pop up in any website  for example

if u  launch www.myntra.com it gives a window like if u have facebook acount login.. am trying to close this facebook window

```
HTML code:

<div class="close"></div>


frist i have tried normal webdriver script

  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='close']").click;

above code gives me exception like "element is not visible you may want to interact with"


i have tried using javaexecutor somthing like below'



WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='close']"));
            JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);


above JS code doesnot give me exception but`enter code here` even it doesnot close the window for which i have written the code.


1)why in above webdriver code i get exception like "element is not visible you may want to interact with"? what is reason behind this.

2) what is the way to close the window?
```

i have spent whole day but dint got solution please help me out thanks in advance

Comment: For security reason JS can only close the window it creates.

Comment: Browser doesn't allow you to do that, the object of created window can call the close method to close the same window. You cannot close any window that was not opened by you using window.open method.

Answer (score 0):

You can close the browser window with Selenium, without Javascript.

```
// get the current windowHandle before triggering the popup (if loading myntra triggers the popup, just navigate to localhost and get the windowHandle there, before navigating to myntra)
String window1 = driver.getWindowHandle();

// trigger the popup
driver.get("www.myntra.com");

// get all window handles
String[] handles = driver.getWindowHandles().toArray(new String[2]);

// switch focus to the popup window
driver.switchTo().window(handles[handles.length - 1]);

// close the popup
driver.close();

// switch focus back to the original window
driver.switchTo().window(window1);

// continue test...
```